# Como pegar ID gerado dinamicamente (JS ou Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero abrir vários poup-up e poder fechar cada qual individualmente, mas só consigo pegar o modal pela classe, pois o id é gerado dinamicamente e eu não já tentei várias formas de pegar para a função funcionar, mas nada. No código mostra funcionando o fechar porque ao clicar pega pelo classe, mas aí fecha todos os abertos e não só o correspondente.

Veja como está o código aqui
https://jsfiddle.net/rgcriativo/kvnrj5x9/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-abrirModal").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var conteudo = $(this).attr("title");
        $(".area-modal").append("<div id='modalid" + id + " ' class='modalm'><section>" + conteudo + "</section><button onclick='fecharModal()' id='fecharModal" + id + "' class='btn-fecharModal'>fechar</button></div>");        
        $("#" + id).css("background-color", "red").css("color", "white").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });    
});

function fecharModal() {
    $(".modalm").remove();
  }
```

```css
.modalm{
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-left:25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="01" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 1">Modal 1</button>
<button id="02" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 2">Modal 2</button>
<button id="03" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 3">Modal 3</button>
<button id="04" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 4">Modal 4</button>
<button id="05" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 5">Modal 5</button>
<button id="06" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 6">Modal 6</button>

<span class="area-modal"></span>
```

Comment: Rodrigo, coloca todo o código aqui pra melhorar a descrição da tua dúvida.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rgcriativo/kvnrj5x9/6/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar na função `fecharModal` qual o elemento está sendo clicado, e através disso fechar somente o modal onde ele está.

No caso, ao adicionar o modal, a função chamada no `onclick` pode passar o próprio elemento `button` como parâmetro.

```js
$(".area-modal").append("<div id='modalid" + id + " ' class='modalm'><section>" + conteudo + "</section><button onclick='fecharModal(this)' id='fecharModal" + id + "' class='btn-fecharModal'>fechar</button></div>");
```

E na função `fecharModal`, uma pequena modificação permite fechar somente o modal referente ao botão clicado. O código completo ficaria assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-abrirModal").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var conteudo = $(this).attr("title");
        $(".area-modal").append("<div id='modalid" + id + " ' class='modalm'><section>" + conteudo + "</section><button onclick='fecharModal(this)' id='fecharModal" + id + "' class='btn-fecharModal'>fechar</button></div>");        
        $("#" + id).css("background-color", "red").css("color", "white").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });    
});

function fecharModal(element) {
  $(element).parents(".modalm").remove();
}
```

```css
.modalm{
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-left:25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="01" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 1">Modal 1</button>
<button id="02" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 2">Modal 2</button>
<button id="03" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 3">Modal 3</button>
<button id="04" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 4">Modal 4</button>
<button id="05" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 5">Modal 5</button>
<button id="06" class="btn-abrirModal" title="Conteúdo do Modal 6">Modal 6</button>

<span class="area-modal"></span>
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito.
Sou novo na plataforma, como faço para dar um DEZ na sua resposta?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers